# Create a better designed database - where to put the foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have 2 tables in my database and 2 Windows Forms (C#) for each table `Section` and `Pages`. Now each `Section` can have 10 `Pages`.

**Note** that I am creating a Windows Forms app and first form looks like this

[FORM 1 (For  Section Table)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvEIf.jpg)

And my second form for table `pages` looks like this:

[FORM 2 for Pages Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpVa6.jpg).

By clicking on each `Section`, user will be directed to the 2nd form where user will/can have 10 pages.

I have this:

```
create table Section
(
    Sectionid int primary key, 
    SectionName varchar,
    Pageid int
) 

create table Page
(
    Pageid int primary key, 
    Pagetitle varchar,
    Noteid int
)
```

```
foreign key(pageid) references Page(pageid)
```

I am confused how to insert data to the database once you have created a page.

**AGAIN**: 1 SECTION CAN HAVE AT LEAST 10 PAGES AND 1 PAGE CAN HAVE 1 NOTE.

If I have not made it easier to understand please just use Microsoft's One Note mobile app, I am basically copying it - thanks.

Comment: Shouldn’t the foreign key be the section ID? And the section table shouldn’t have pageId?

Comment: Thats one confusion.

Comment: If you want to have up to 10 pages per section, you need `SectionId int foreign key references dbo.Section(SectionId)` in your `Page` table

Comment: If you need to show images please ensure they are concise i.e. don't have large amounts of whitespace which clog up the screen, and make sure they are of a resolution/scale that views well and is not too large.

Comment: So Section table will only have 2 attributes SectionID and SectionName right ? Considering i only have 3 sections.

Comment: @marc_s  tell me .... as soon as page is created so does a Note is created for that page . Now how i add the noteId in Page table . I can not retreive the noteId from Note with help of WHERE keyword, because Note And Page have nothing in common.

Comment: Should i inter relate both  tables ? I mean to put foreign keys in both tables

Answer (score 0):

The relation between section an page is 1: n.

You can formulate it as:
One section has multiple pages, but one page only has one section. You always have to put the foreign key in the "n" table, which is in this case the "page".

So you have something like that, tell me your database and I can write you a exact sql:

```
Create Table Section(
  Sectionid int primary key,
  SectionName varchar,
)

Create Table Page(
  Pageid int,
  pagetitle int,
  Noteid int,
  PRIMARY KEY(PageId),
  FOREIGN KEY (SectionId) References Section(SectionId)
)
```

...but I guess the pagetitle is also a varchar?

If you want to insert data, it is easy for the section. A simple insert statement. If you want insert data in the page object, you have to insert the id of the section for the column "SectionId".

Example:

```
Insert into table Section (Sectionid, SectionName) values (12,'test');
Insert into table Page (Pageid, Sectionid) values(1,12);
```

The value "12" you insert is the id of the section.

Comment: Your foreign key syntax isn't correct you need to specify which table it references.

Comment: Got ur point thanks and yes pagetitle is varchar i have edited

Comment: Considering i can only have 3 Sections and i have already inserted 3 rows into the Section's table. Now the user created a new Page inside one of the section, now how do i know that to which Section user have inserted page. So i can specify the sectionid in my Page Table.

Comment: And then each Page will have 1 Note. how to relate these two tables?(Page and Notes)

Comment: You know in which section the user created the page, and you add this sectionid to the page.

The Page and Note Tables are then probably 1:1, that means you can add the Foreign key in the Page table as well as in the Note table. As you need it.
Or can a note appear in more than one page?

Comment: each page will sure have a single note , note may be empty but it does exist. if page exists than so do the note

Comment: So why not have the Note as a column in the Page table?

Comment: For Note i have created a new table, basically so that i can have more tables to be honest. It is for my university project.

Answer (score 0):

once you introduce constraints into the schema you need to be deliberate with how to insert data.

(temp tables don't enforce constraints like this)

```
CREATE TABLE #Pages    (PageID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, PageTitle NVARCHAR(20), NoteID INT)
CREATE TABLE #Sections (SectionID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, SectionName NVARCHAR(20), PageID INT CONSTRAINT FK_PageID REFERENCES #Pages(PageID))
```

Now we have our tables, complete with constraints. The FK must exist in the referenced table.

```
DECLARE @KeyTable TABLE (PageID INT)

INSERT INTO #Pages (PageTitle, NoteID) 
OUTPUT INSERTED.PageID INTO @KeyTable
VALUES ('Some Page', NULL)

INSERT INTO #Sections (SectionName, PageID) 
SELECT 'Some Section', PageID
  FROM @KeyTable
INSERT INTO #Sections (SectionName, PageID) 
SELECT 'Another Section', PageID
  FROM @KeyTable
```

When we insert a page we can capture the ID generated (or provided if it's not also an identity) and hold it in a table variable. We can then use it in the insert into Sections as well.
When you're actually doing this you may want to build some logic around checking if a page already exists and populating the table variable with the appropriate existing PageID if it does or doing the insert and propulating the PageID this way if it does not.